# NSURL Error Code 1022

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an RSS reader app, that has a parser. It has worked well, up until iOS 9 beta. Whenever I try to load data, I get error code 1022. Here is my code for establishing a connection:

```
- (void)parseRssFeed:(NSString *)url withDelegate:(id)aDelegate {
[self setDelegate:aDelegate];

responseData = [NSMutableData data];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];


NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:baseURL];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

And the error handler:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSString * errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to download XML data (Error code %i )", [error code]];

UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error loading content" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];
}
```

I'm not sure what changed between iOS 8 and 9, but for some reason the app no longer works. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the URL you're hitting satisfy App Transport Security? If not you'll need to update the server or create an exception in your config https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/

Comment: Okay, so I've been looking into the ATS thing. I don't think my URL statisfies it, but I don't understand how I can create the exception. It says I need to update my info.plist, but I'm not sure how to work with plists, as I've never made any changes to my app's info.plist

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So, the problem had to do with ATS (App Transport Security), a new feature in iOS 9 that checks the authenticity of a URL before connecting to it. As I am not concerned about the secure-ness of the website I'm connecting to, I disabled ATS entirely. This can be done by adding the following code to the app's info.plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: It would probably help others if your answer explained what ATS is and what you needed to add to Info.plist.

Comment: This link has more information and a tutorial: http://timekl.com/blog/2015/08/21/shipping-an-app-with-app-transport-security/

Answer (score 5):

for swift4 add this in app's info.plist

```
<key>App Transport Security Settings</key>
<dict>
<key>Allow Arbitrary Loads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

**or**

go to app's info.plist

Right click and select `Add Row`
and find `App Transport Security Settings` and click it.
then again Right click on `App Transport Security Settings` and select `Add Row`
then find and click `Allow Arbitrary Loads` and modify its value to `YES`.

Autocomplete when typing "App Transport...." or "Allow Arbitrary..." can be slow or nonexistent, so you can either wait it out or type it anyway and then click on "Value" side of list (to the right) and write YES (for Allow Arbitrary Loads).  App Transport Security Settings won't have a "Value" until you add the Arbitrary Loads, then it will say "(1 item)"

Answer (score 0):

I added the suggestion in the accepted answer, but it still didn't work. I had to change the `http` to `https` in my case, and it worked (even though I wasn't using a secure url).

Answer (score -1):

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

NSString *stringUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting"];
NSString *webStringURL=[stringUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                   completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
         {
NSDictionary *dicYourResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];
             NSLog(@"ID: %@", [dicYourResponse objectForKey:@"id"]);
             NSLog(@"Content:%@", [dicYourResponse objectForKey:@"content"]);
         }
     }];
}
```

I have done this to hit the url, its build successfully but no answer in console. I have added App transport security and exception Domain in info.plist also it's not working for me.

Comment: First, post a proper question, *as a question.*